# Mongoose aggregation pipeline: Comparing to own object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a sample mongoose object that looks like this:

```
  {
    _id: 5fa849ad4f6be0382363809c,
    ratings: {
      ratedPersonId: 7,
      rating: 7,
      timeSpent: 30,
      timestamp: 78,
      userThreshold: 5
    }
  },
```

it contains an `_id` and a list of ratings which is a subdocument with the following features.

I have created an aggregation pipeline like this:

```
    const ratedUser = await this.ratingModel
      .aggregate([
        { $project: { ratings: 1 } },
        { $unwind: '$ratings' },
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [{ 'ratings.ratedPersonId': userId }, { 'ratings.rating': { $gte: 5 } }],
          },
        },
      ])
      .exec()
```

This works for the first condition `ratings.ratedPersonId: userId`

My problem is that my second condition is the rating should be greater than or equal to the `userThreshold` field in the same object.

whenever I type that in the query it returns nothing

```
 $and: [{ 'ratings.ratedPersonId': userId }, { 'ratings.rating': { $gte: 'ratings.threshold'} }],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/AQMsJGkoFcu

Use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) to compare the fields

Read [aggregation-expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions)

> $expr can build query expressions that compare fields from the same document in a $match stage.
> If the $match stage is part of a $lookup stage, $expr can compare fields using let variables. See Specify Multiple Join Conditions with $lookup for an example.
> $expr only uses indexes on the from the collection for equality matches in a $match stage.
> $expr does not support multikey indexes.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      ratings: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$ratings"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "ratings.ratedPersonId": 7
        },
        {
          $expr: {
            $gte: [
              "$ratings.rating",
              "$ratings.userThreshold"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. Can you explain why we are using `$ratings.rating` (dollar sign notation) in the `$expr: {...}` statement?

Comment: @Ating we have to use aggregation-expressions in `$expr` you can read here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions